# database cluster failed: error : Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am currently stuck on one of the issue of dynamic CRM.

My dynamic CRM application is not running in pre-prod environment and showing message like No Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID.

A few months back, the db cluster failed of this application in pre-prod db server hence I lost database but after that I took database copy from production and restore on pre-production db server, but now my dynamic CRM application is showing message like No Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID.

Maybe it is Active directory related issue not sure cause due to db cluseter failure I took production database into pre-prod db server environment and as of now Pre-prod application is pointing to db which I actually took from production.

Answer (score 0):

To clone PROD in STAGING the process is pretty straightforward

```
[STAGING Environment]
    Delete the organization through the CRM Deployment Manager
    Delete the <ORGNAME>_MSCRM database

[PRODUCTION Environment]
    Backup <ORGNAME>_MSCRM database (can be done live)
    Copy the backup to STAGING sql

[STAGING Environment again]
    Restore the copied backup
    Import organization in deployment manager (users will be mapped automatically)
```

Comment: Essentially, this is how an organization is copied from one CRM to another, can be a useful process for a number of scenarios.